# Database unusable whist doing a database restore (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I was asked to create a database from a backup for reporting and whilst transferring the file from backup to a disk on the server the database became unusable.

Then again whist running the restore script, it was again running incredibly slowly.  Not sure if it is a configuration issue...

- SQL server is running on an ESXi host (4.0 Build 398348)
- Win 2008 R2
- 8GB Ram (SQL has most of this)
- Single CPU (due to licencing)
- Storage is locally attached rather than SAN/NAS
- SAS disks 10k (I think)

Here is the backup script (fairly standard)

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'E:\Backup\[DatabaseName].bak'

RESTORE DATABASE [DatabaseName]
FROM DISK = 'E:\Backup\[DatabaseName].bak'
WITH 
    MOVE '[DatabaseName]_Data' TO 'E:\DatabaseFiles\[DatabaseName].mdf',
    MOVE '[DatabaseName]_Log' TO 'E:\LogFiles\[DatabaseName]_log.ldf'

ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET MULTI_USER
```

Folders DatabaseFiles and LogFiles are mounted NDFS partitions.

Are there any tests I could perform to identify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the server runs virtualized, there is a good chance you are running into an I/O bottleneck. Check your disk performance counters in the Windows guest - [specifically idle time and queue length](http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a66/how-to-using-nt-performance-monitor-hdd-utilization.aspx) - and take a look at ESXi's "Datastore" and "Storage adapter" latency performance counters - a decently performing storage would show values in the magnitude of 10 ms there. If you see more than 100 ms, the storage is probably overloaded.

Comment: As I thought.. I followed the guidance on the link you provided - although it peaked and then levelled off (although a smaller file) Any recommendations?  Would moving it to a different raid in the server (which currently has nothing on it) make any difference?  Or is it the way the disk is configured?

Comment: Usually write I/O is the problem - ESXi does a lot of synchronous writes - if the server does not have a RAID controller with **write cache enabled** (which it should only be if there is a BBU or another construct to prevent cached data loss on power loss for consistency reasons) you are going to see terrible performance.

Comment: It has a raid controller but I don't know if write cache is enabled.  I believe the raid controller does have a BBU and UPS.  Thanks for your help - I think you may have found the problem!